# Import data with "labels" and "values" from SPSS to MATLAB

Tags: matlab, spss

How can I import the 'labels' and 'values' from SPSS to MATLAB? What I usually do is to convert the .sav file to an excel file and then import it to MATLAB. However the 'labels' and 'values' are not registered in the excel file. Anyway I can access them? Thank you.

Comment: what is the format of the .sav file? What does it look like?

Comment: can you export the data to another format than .sav and read the file using `importdata` or fscanf` or `textread` perhaps?

Comment: When using SPSS to export to excel you can save the *value labels* instead of the actual values.